# Nexus 7 - moving pictures/videos to pc

Tags: tablet

Have hooked by tablet up to a computer using a USB cord.  I have over 500 pictures and videos that I want moved to my computer, but when I click on the nexus 7 folder, it's blank.
I have been able to do this before so quick and easy, but not sure what the dealio is now.
Help!!!!!

Comment: Did your computer recently upgrade to Win10, and have you checked your drivers? The driver may be incompatible with Win10, and need a complementary upgrade, too.

Answer (score 0):

If your N7 has been upgraded to Marshmallow (Android 6.0.x), then when connected, look for a notification in the notification dropdown that lets you change USB mode to "file transfer".